# calling sharepoint webservice in ios with phonegap

Tags: ios, html, cordova, sharepoint-2010

I am new to phonegap. I need to call SharePoint web service to my ios app with phonegap in html5. Can anyone help? How can it be called? Is is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Although i am not sure what type of data your service returns but generally it returns XML, so this plugin might help you easily capture the data and process the output in regular JSON format.

https://github.com/bobby/jquery-sharepoint-json

Also include your service ip address in the whitelist otherwise it will not be reachable due to cordova security model [Domain Whitelist](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide).

Comment: output is user image and their information

Comment: in which format output is coming, xml, json or different